# How to Call javascript function on button click of Repeater event Repeater1_ItemDataBound

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to open pop window on button click of repeater according to id which is binding to current row.I write this javascript function which I want to call according to row id which is unique.Then this java script function called from ItemDataBound event of repeater.

```
   This is java script code :

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(lblEduCatId) {
            window.onload = function() {
                var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
                var btn = document.getElementById("<%=btnAccess.ClientID %>").value;
                var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

                btn.onclick = function() {
                    modal.style.display = "block";
                }

                span.onclick = function() {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }

                window.onclick = function(event) {
                    if (event.target == modal) {
                        modal.style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    </script>


.cs code

 protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            string lblEduCatId = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "EduCatId").ToString();
            string lblIsFree = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "IsFree").ToString();
            string lblAccess = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Access").ToString();


            Button access = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnAccess");
            access.OnClientClick = "return test(lblEduCatId);";

            if (Session["UserName"] != null)
            {
                if (lblAccess.ToString() == "True")
                {
                    access.Text = "Access";
                    access.CommandName = "Access";
                }
                else
                {
                    access.Text = "Subscribe";
                    access.CommandName = "Subscribe";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (lblIsFree.ToString() == "True")
                {
                    access.Text = "Access";
                    access.CommandName = "Access";
                }
                else
                {
                    access.Text = "Subscribe";
                    access.CommandName = "Subscribe";
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the code behind:

```
Button access = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnAccess");
access.OnClientClick = "test(" + lblEduCatId + "); return false;";
```

And on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(lblEduCatId) {
    //open the modal with the correct lblEduCatId received from the repeater
}
</script>
```

Your current code will not work because in Repeater1_ItemDataBound you don't add the variable lblEduCatId to the OnClientClick, just 'lblEduCatId' as a plain text string and without quotes at that.
Second in the javascript you use

```
var btn = document.getElementById("<%=btnAccess.ClientID %>").value;
```

This also won't work because btnAccess does not exist in that context. In the repeater every button has it's own clientID.

Comment: Thanks for your answer that helped to resolve my problem.